# Why my unit test do not work in MVC (assert.areequal failed.expected:<Tabular>.Actual)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, model-view-controller

I am working on MVC and it is my first unit test so exucse me if there is stupid i do.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using WebApplication2.Controllers;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication2.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var ctrl = new HomeController();
            var res = ctrl.tableData1("AllDevices") as ViewResult;
            Assert.AreEqual("tableData1", res.ViewName);
        }
    }
}
```

Where HomeController ActionResult() is:

```
 public ActionResult tableData1(string status)
        {

            List<tableData1> tableDataModel = new List<tableData1>();
                      tableDataModel.Add(new tableData1()
            {
                ID="1",
                Name = "Shekhar",
                Status = "AllVehicles",               
                Location = "Pilani",
                Odometer = "check1",
                PS = "BatteryOff",
                IG = "PowerOf",
                GPS = "GpsOf",
                AC = "Off",
                Door = "-",
                Speed = "152Km/Hr",
                Fuel = "14000 Ltrs",
                Temp = "52",
                State = "Stopped",
                Map = "Map click",
                Time = "1:00PM",
                Lat = "28.3802817",
                Long = "75.6070956"
            });
                 if (status != "AllVehicles")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tableDataModel.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (status != tableDataModel[i].Status)
                    {
                        tableDataModel.RemoveAt(i);
                        i--;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (status == "AllVehicles")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tableDataModel.Count; i++) { } //useless
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Inside else condition");
            }
            return View(tableDataModel);
        }
```

When i try to do this i obtain an error like this : http://prntscr.com/7lwe0c

Could some one please let me know why i have this error and how to solve it ?

Comment: if you return VIew(), i mean without parameter - it's called view as action name. Your code will work only if pass parameter name in view(though it is pointless), for example return View("Tabular")

Comment: @lgor i changed the code and same error (could you please see my new controller) ?

Comment: `return View(tableDataModel);` should be - `return View("tableData1",tableDataModel);`

Comment: @ramiramilu there is no error but also there is no output . see this http://prntscr.com/7lwuzu  Also please exlpain  how this change corrected problem ?

Comment: Have you went through the link I shared, by default `return View()` doesn't include your ViewName, so you need to explicitly tell the name of the View, just like what I showed in above comment. Coming back to no output, I see there is `return Content()` in your code, in that case test will not work, because it is not going to be a `ViewResult`. One more thing, you View should be named as `tableData1`, any other name test will fail. Also one suggestion what I would give to is that, debug the unit test to get to know where exactly it is failing.

Comment: @ramiramilu , NO In if status != "AllVehicles and in elseif(status == "AllVehicles). Ok lets say i have changed the Status to "status == "AllVehicles"  now it will not go in  Content(..); part. it will go in 2nd condition. But still no output.

Comment: Can I know what you mean by no output?